# How to clone a dynamic reference to an observablecollection of generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, collections

I have a class like :

```
class A    
{
    string name{get;set;}
    dynamic values{get;set;} // this can be either ObservableCollection of type string, or MyClass1 or MyClass2
}
```

I want to clone this object. (it is okay to have of shallow clone of collection), below is how I am doing this now, is there any better way to do this?

```
public A Clone()
{
    A obj = new A();
    obj.name = a.name;
    if(values is ObservableCollection<string>)
    {
        obj.values = new ObservableCollection<string>((ObservableCollection<string>)collection);
    }
    else if(values is ObservableCollection<MyClass1>)
    {
        obj.values = new ObservableCollection<MyClass1>((ObservableCollection<MyClass1>)collection);
    } 
    else if(values is ObservableCollection<MyClass2>)
    {
        obj.values = new ObservableCollection<MyClass2>((ObservableCollection<MyClass2>)collection);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like weak architecture for me, I would try to define it at least as `IEnumerable`, but not `dynamic`. However it could be ok for an internal use.

You can try it like this:

```
public A Clone()
{
    A obj = new A();
    obj.name = name;
    obj.values = Activator.CreateInstance(values.GetType(), values);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: oh ya, i didn't think of making it IEnumerable. personally i don't prefer using dynamic at all. will try to change if possible ")

Comment: I am not sure how can i replace dynamic with IEnumerable? it doesn't seem compatible with generic IEnumerable<>. Any inputs u can provide?

Comment: Hm, the problem is I don't know your requirements. If you are not sure - don't replace it and use it as it is now. The main point here for cloning your collection is this line `obj.values = Activator.CreateInstance(values.GetType(), values);`. Does it help?

Comment: plz see if u can help http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233175/suggest-architecture-for-classes-that-maps-to-json-with-dynamic-without-using-dy